# Unexpected ending at prepositional case of "компания"

Tags: суффиксы

I have came across a sentence which contains the following words in the prepositional case.

> "вашей компании"

I could not figure out why компания transformed into компании (why double **и** at the end; my expectation is single **и**?).

Is there a specific rule that if there is a **"ия"** at the end of the word, it would transform as **"ии"**. Or, is it an exception?

Comment: It is not a suffix, it is ending.

Comment: really, I was not aware. Do you know any source which explains how to distunguish suffixes and endings.

Comment: @stackr "Ending" is just the last "morphing suffix" (if any) in Russian. Obviously, English doesn't distinguish between the suffixes as it has no declension at all.

Comment: In Russian we usually treat "endings" (inflections) differently from suffixes because an ending does not change the meaning of the word as defined in the dictionary. Prefixes and suffixes make new words. That is why reflexive "-ся" is a suffix: "мыть" and "мыться" are different words. Though, since in Russian tradition ending is "always after the suffixes", they typically call СЯ "a postfix" in school.

Comment: As far as I understood, using "ending" instead of "suffix" is more appropriate because it is more specific. But, using "suffix" is not wrong. It can still be used. Am I right?

Comment: @stackr It is different for agglutinative languages where suffixes are your bread and butter to regularly perfom grammatical transformations over the word.

Comment: postfix and suffix are synonyms. is that right?

Comment: @stackr Yes. As for the difference between inflections and suffixes, note that inflected languages squeeze a lot of information into one ending. Let's take the sentence "She *likes* him". The ending "-s" means that you are using Present Simple, it also means it is 3rd person, singular. Suffixes in agglutinative languages do not work that way. They usually express one focused grammatical meaning at a time. If you need two concepts expressed, you attach two suffixes.

Comment: Then basically, the title of the question "unexpected suffix" is wrong. So I will change it. Thanks for your helps.

Comment: Suffix is part of stem, ending is not.

Comment: In English -er, -ter is suffix, -s, -es is ending. work-er-s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [Wiktionary tells us](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F), the word "компания" splits into root -компани- and inflection -я:

> Корень: -компани-; окончание: -я

In all cases, only inflection changes ([same source](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)):

```
падеж  ед. ч.   мн. ч.
Им.  компáния   компáнии
Р.   компáнии   компáний
Д.   компáнии   компáниям
В.   компáнию   компáнии
Тв.  компáнией  компáниями
     компáниею
Пр.  компáнии   компáниях
```

So it is a general rule.

**Update:** I think I have understood why you were expecting a single **и** here.

If you have a double consonant, like **нн**, it usually pronounced in the same way as a single one. But there is no such case double vowel; all vowel sounds are pronounced *independently*. Listen [here](http://forvo.com/word/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8/#ru).

Comment: How the root can be компани if we have "компанейский"?

Comment: @Anixx, how you suggest to split it?

Comment: Actually, the reason why I confused that I had assumed the root of the word as "компан". thanks, it was very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, always like this. The ending is only one letter, so last but one letter remains as is. This is true not only for **-ия** but also for several other similar endings: **-ие**, **-ея** etc.

Answer (score 1):

В родительном и предложном падежах у имён существительных "компания", "мания", "талия", "версия" и т.п. окончание **ии**. Нет кого-чего? - компании, мании, талии, версии. Думаю о ком-о чём? - о компании, о мании, о талии, о версии.